# Is there a way to set dyno restart time in heroku?

Tags: heroku

I deployed a to-do web service in heroku.

But I didn't know that saving file is only ephemeral.

It's still fine because my to-do is only for a day.

But I want it to be reset on 4 am to maintain the data for a day

Is there anyways to manually set dyno restarting time?

Or is there some free service which provides saving besides heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to schedule the restart time.

Using the Heroku CLI I guess you can script it (meaning your computer needs to be on all the times).

Be aware that a free Dyno goes to sleep after 30 min inactivity (no incoming traffic). Once asleep the first request will make it start again.
You should look at storing the file somewhere else (save it on Google docs or Amazon S3) so you don't lose your data if the Dyno restarts.

Comment: thank you so much! I will try to look at Google docs or Amazon S3!